# Rewriteurl in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

in my site I need to rewrite some url but I'm not capable 
to define RewriteRule and RewriteCond conditions:

http://www.stiloweb.it/component/search/?keyword=**KEYWORDS**&searchwordsugg=&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&view=category

should become

http://www.stiloweb.it/component/virtuemart/?keyword=**KEYWORDS**&search=true&view=category&option=com_virtuemart&virtuemart_category_id=0

I'm hoping for some help.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this rule to the top of your htacess file om your document root:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keyword=([^&]+)&searchwordsugg=&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&view=category$
RewriteRule ^component/search/$ /componet/virtuemart/?keyword=%1&search=true&view=category&option=com_virtuemart&virtuemart_category_id=0 [L,R]
```